# Finding where Pandera schemas are different

Tags: python, pandas, validation, schema, pandera

I have two Pandas data frames `df1` and `df2` which *should* have the same inferred Pandera schema. Unfortunately they do not because when I run `pa.infer_schema(df1) != pa.infer_schema(df2)` I get a return of `False`. The print out (which should be `__repr__`) of these schema look identical under visual inspection, so I suspect the difference is something having to do with different instances. But I am unsure about that.

How can I get a "diff" between Pandera schema to help me more quickly understand why they are not equal?

Answer (score 0):

I found that [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) on the output of [DeepDiff](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/6.2.3/diff.html) revealed that the minima and maxima of certain columns were different between the data frames! Inferring these min/max constraints was not behavior I expected or desired default.